# Controller action in IFrame "src" attribute - YII Framework

Tags: javascript, iframe, yii

I am trying to call the controller action in IFrame src,

```
$('#iframe').attr('src', 'controller/action');
```

How to call the controller action in the above line inside JavaScript function ?

```
 <?php
 echo CHtml::imageButton(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/new.jpg'
,array('id'=>'reflist-button'
,'style'=>'display:inline-block',
'onclick'=>'$("#cru-frame-RefNew").attr("src","-----How to call controller action -------"); 
$("#RefList-New").dialog("open"); return false;'));?>
```

Comment: calling controller action? show your full script please

Comment: why dont you use the full url of the controller action like 'http://localhost/projectname/index.php/controller/action'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
// save your url in a varible first
$myPath=Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action');
```

and then change this

```
'onclick'=>"$('#cru-frame-RefNew').attr('src',$myPath); 
$('#RefList-New').dialog('open'); return false;"
```